# Frontespizio problem in report document

Tags: thesis, report, frontespizio

I'm a fresh LaTeX user and I'm trying to write my thesis project by using it.
I read about the package "frontespizio" and it looks really intresting, since my thesis project has to be written in English, but I'm italian.

I'm using the following code. No error displayed, but it does not write anything...just a white page. Can you help me, please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[nouppercase]{frontespizio}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}
\Istituzione{Universit/'a delle favole}
\Divisione{Dipartimento di qualcosa}
\Scuola{Laurea in boh}
\Titolo{Titolo della questione}
\Sottotitolo{Sottotitolo}
\NCandidato{Candidate}
\Candidato{Nome Cognome}
\NRelatore{Thesis advisor}
\Relatore{Nome Cognome}
\Ncorrelatore{Research supervisor}{Research supervisors}
\Correlatore{Nome Cognome}
\Correlatore{Nome Cognome}
\Piede{Matr. 111111}

\end{frontespizio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your file called `maoloMasterThesis.tex`? If so, you need to separately compile `maoloMasterThesis-frn.tex` to produce the title page. The log file gives a clear message about it.

Comment: Also, it should be `\NCorrelatore{Research supervisor}{Research supervisors}` (note the uppercase C)

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about log file hints. It works properly now!

Answer (score 2):

If your master file is called `mythesis.tex`, then running LaTeX over it will save a new file called `mythesis-frn.tex` in the same folder as the master file. You have to run LaTeX on it and the next time you compile the thesis file, the frontispiece will be included.

This operation is needed only after you change the frontispiece data.

The operation can be made automatic if you use `arara`, by adding the magic line

```
% arara: frontespizio
```

at the top of the file.

Note that `Universit/'a` should be `` Universit\`a `` and

```
\Ncorrelatore{Research supervisor}{Research supervisors}
```

should be

```
\NCorrelatore{Research supervisor}{Research supervisors}
```

The package manual is in Italian, from your comments I gather you can read it.